# Get two date formats from jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I have a simple datepicker text field:

```
<input type="text" name="book_on" id="book_on" value="<?php echo $today; ?>"
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
$('#book_on').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y'
      });
```

This is all very straight-forward, but I also need to show the chosen date in a different format elsewhere on the page - specifically, when a date is chosen, I need to show which day of the week it is in a `<span>` on the page.

This would be `dateFormat: 'D'` but I can't find a way to get the datepicker to return a second type of date format. I don't need the whole code written, if you could just get the function above to alert the day of the week for the chosen date, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CbKey/)**?

jQuery:

```
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$('#book_on').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y',
    onSelect: function(event, ui) {
        var dayOfWeek = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getUTCDay();
        $('#day').val(days[dayOfWeek]);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Amazing! :) I bet you got array for days from w3schools :P

Comment: @VisioN - Sorry, I avoid w3schools.

Comment: it has a hardcoded array of day names in it, and fails to make use of the included function _specifically designed for this purpose_.

Comment: @Alnitak Possibly our solutions are not the best but they are workable. Downvoting for that is a bad attitude IMHO.

Comment: @Alnitak - Down votes are for answers that are "not useful", not debating the best way you personally feel a solution should be coded.

Comment: @j08691  no, my down votes are for answers that espouse bad practises or unnecessarily re-invent the wheel.   Don't even get me started on your archaic array construction and the time-zone related bug...

Answer (score 7):

A little late to the party, but the real solution, I believe, is to make use of the two datepicker properties

```
    altField: "#your-span",
    altFormat: "D",
```

[Setting these options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) will automatically fill the element `#your-span` with the proper format. No extra code needed!

Comment: good spot - very useful if the requirement is just to fill in another field on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onSelect` event and do the trick like that:

```
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
$("#book_on").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var day = new Date(dateText).getDay();
        $("span").text(weekday[day]);
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LXCMD/

Answer (score 0):

> This would be dateFormat: 'D' but I can't find a way to get the datepicker to return a second type of date format.

The Datepicker plugin has a [utility function](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) specifically for outputting dates in any format you want, e.g.

```
var t = $('#picker').datepicker('getDate');
var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('D', t);
```

hence:

```
$('#book_on').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#span').text($.datepicker.formatDate('D', date));
    }
});​
```

Comment: Awesome - this is the code I needed, this worked perfectly. ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐